# Set autocmd for every time I change file

Tags: vim

How can I set up a `autcmd` command for every time I switch to another file?

I want to call to a `Rooter` command (a plugin for setting the root directory).

What I've tried:

`au BufEnter * Rooter`

But it's not working always, sometimes when I select a file from MRU for instance.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set up a autcmd command for every time I switch to another file?

From your description, I think you need event `BufLeave` ?

if your `Rooter()` is a function,

```
au BufLeave * call Rooter()
```

Comment: I've already tried with BufLeave also. But I don't know why is not always working...

Comment: Regarding the function `Error detected while processing BufEnter Auto commands for "*":
E117: Unknown function: Rooter`

Comment: @vivoconunxino 2b honest, I don't understand clearly when you want Rooter() to be called.

Comment: Because I want to be sure that every time I switch to a different file, I am in the root directory of my project (pwd=my root project folder)

Comment: @vivoconunxino you didn't understand what is command and what is function.... it seems that `Rooter` is a custom command, instead of function.

Comment: then `BufEnter` would be the right one. @vivoconunxino

Comment: That's what I tried, but somehow vim interprets that buffer was already open on a previous session and doesn't trigger that event (BufEnter) when trying with MRU on a recent file. That's why I was asking for any other way

Answer (score 0):

What you are after it is already implemented in the plugin itself:

see: [vim-rooter's source code](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter/blob/70c105cbcf3ce19b92ddec8fa498e49ada79744b/plugin/rooter.vim#L161)

So no need to implement it yourself. I think you should make plugin, **buffer local**! so replace all occurances of `g:loaded_rooter` with `b:loaded_rooter` in [source code](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter/blob/70c105cbcf3ce19b92ddec8fa498e49ada79744b/plugin/rooter.vim#L6-L9). then save, close vim, open and test.